# Best way to modify a built-in TensorFlow kernel

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to learn the best way to modify TensorFlow built-in operator kernels.
For example, I want to modify the value of `static const double A` in `tensorflow/core/kernels/resize_bicubic_op.cc`. I have come up with two possible ways:

1. Modify it directly and recompile the whole TensorFlow library. The problems of this solution are: A. This influences all the functions which use bicubic interpolation. B. This requires me to recompile the entire library and does not work when installing from a binary.
2. Define it as a custom op. The problem is that in the source code, there is no `REGISTER_OP()` inside. I don't know how to write the `REGISTER_OP()` for this bicubic function and whether other modification needs to be made.

Are there other better ways?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to approach this problem is to build a custom op. See [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html) for more details about how to add custom ops in general. The `REGISTER_OP` call for the [`tf.image.resize_bicubic()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/image.html#resize_bicubic) op is in [`tensorflow/core/ops/image_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8cb0558da924e891aa1bb5d79a6c0c846301e4eb/tensorflow/core/ops/image_ops.cc#L128).

Another alternative is to re-use the same *op* registration, and register a new *kernel* with the alternative implementation. This would enable you to use the (experimental) [`Graph.kernel_label_map()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8cb0558da924e891aa1bb5d79a6c0c846301e4eb/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3311) API to select an alternative implementation for the `"ResizeBicubic"` op. For example, you could do the following in your Python program:

```
_ = tf.load_op_library(...)  # Load the .so containing your implementation.

with tf.get_default_graph().kernel_label_map({"ResizeBicubic": "my_impl"}):
  images = tf.image.resize_bicubic(...)  # Will use your implementation.
```

...and add a kernel registration that specifies the label `"my_impl"` with your C++ code:

```
template <typename Device, typename T>
class MyResizeBicubicOp<Device, T> : public OpKernel {
  // Custom implementation goes here...
}

#define REGISTER_KERNEL(T)                            \
  REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("ResizeBicubic")       \
                              .Device(DEVICE_CPU)     \
                              .Label("my_impl")       \
                              .TypeConstraint<T>("T") \
                              .HostMemory("size"),    \
                          MyResizeBicubicOp<CPUDevice, T>);

TF_CALL_REAL_NUMBER_TYPES(REGISTER_KERNEL);
```

Comment: Thank you mrry. I have tried both the methods and they are working. However, the performance is very bad. The custom op is 10x slower than the built-in resize_bicubic. I directly copied the code from Tensorflow's  resize_bicubic implementation without changing anything (except the modification required by adding this new op). Is it normal?

Comment: A 10x slowdown is surprising. Have you checked that the compiler optimization flags are the same when building your extension?

Comment: I use the commands provided in the tutorial: TF_INC=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())'); g++ -std=c++11 -shared zero_out.cc -o zero_out.so -fPIC -I $TF_INC

Comment: Try passing `-O2 -DNDEBUG` as well.

Comment: Yes. This solves the slowdown problem. Is it possible to update the tutorial?

Comment: Sure - there's a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/4195) pending.